# How to reject incoming e-mail with Postfix?

Tags: postfix

I would like `postfix` to not accept incoming mail. I do however use it for sending e-mail, so I cannot simply uninstall it.

How can I configure `postfix` to reject all incoming mail?

Comment: any clues in this link? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I used mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = localhost   but I still get mensages I want don't get more mensages  for keep server clean

Comment: So you don't want your server to have any email at all?  Why not run `apt remove postfix` then?

Comment: I would like to still send e-mail but don't storage the e-mails received like no-reply

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes I reworded the question according to your comments, and nominated it for re-opening. Please have a look at it, and check that it looks ok :)

Comment: If you are running a server connected to the Internet, you must maintain an e-mail address where other Internet users can contact you about it, such as to notify you of issues with your server (spam, etc.).

Comment: Not voting to reopen because really, people running mail servers despite having no idea what they are doing are why spam is such a huge problem, and we should not support it.

Comment: @fkraiem So because spam is a problem, you are not voting to reopen an on topic question on askubuntu? Properly assisting a user in configuring the mail server could *reduce* spam as well.

Comment: This server is only using the e-mails to send to an other server that is why I don't need become contacted throw this server. @fkraiem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described as a [null client](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#null_client) in Postfix' documentation.

Configure postfix to only listen to loop back by changing `inet_listen` to

```
inet_listen = loopback-only
```

in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

This effectively blocks incoming connections, disallowing mail delivery. In addition, you should set

```
my_destinations =
```

This disables *all* local mail delivery. This should obviously only be used if you want mail for e.g. root and similar (typically crontab-generated) to be sent to an external host. If you want local delivery of such mail, leave `my_destinations` as is.

Postfix' documentation has some more information about your attempted configuration, including full explanations of options.

Comment: I will try this solution when I get chance to check it and I will give you the feedback.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help